# Are all legendary Pokemon the same CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

So far, I haven't fought many legendary Pokemon but the ones I fought, all the Articunoes have been the same CP (37,603) and Lugias as well (42,753). So do legendary Pokemon as raid bosses the same CP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, all legendary pokemon of the same species have the same CP value.

[*Source*](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-07-24-pokemon-go-raids-raid-battles-raid-bosses-raid-passes-raid-rewards-4819)

Answer (score 8):

All *raid bosses* have the [same CP value](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/raid-boss-list) for any given Pokémon species, because they all have the same IV values and level.  This is true whether you are talking Legendary or not.

The Pokémon itself (the one you catch) will *not* have the identical CP values; they range like the Pokémon you catch from eggs (10/10/10 to 15/15/15, level 20).